# Sharpdevelop Report generator with SQlite

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, report, sharpdevelop

I am an A-Level student. I have to use sharpdevelop (VB.net) for this project and I need to create and print reports to create bills for each client. I also have to use SQLite (using SQLite Admim as my database client).

In sharpdevelop there is a report generator but I need it to talk to my sqlite database. However it won't let me! Does anyone out there have a solution to get round this? Either in sharpdevelop or sending the data to another piece of software? but I have to remain in sharpdevelop.

Please remember I am only a novice and I need it in simple terms please.

Comment: "I am an A-Level student": Congratulations. I am honored to deal with so highly-accomplished individuals. Unfortunately this is an F-level question. Please, take a look at the help pages to understand how you should be asking questions here.

Comment: poor teacher... [Is anyone using System.Data.SQLite within SharpDevelop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083187/is-anyone-using-system-data-sqlite-within-sharpdevelop), [ADD, EDIT, DELETE, SEARCH - C# and SQLite](http://www.sourcecodester.com/c/3972/add-edit-delete-search-c-and-sqlite.html)

Comment: I know SQL etc! The problem here is different! It only gives me the option in the data source drop down to connect to an SQL Server and it doesn't like me trying to connect to an SQLite database! Considering i have been programming less than a year i am doing well if you could see my project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharpDevelop Report Generator currently only supports SQL Server.

You will need to look at using a different report generator. If you are creating a PDF report then a library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/) may help. SharpDevelop's Report Generator uses iTextSharp to generate its PDF reports.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I shall look into these other pieces of software!